# Producing a random sequence of integers... 30 times

Tags: r, random, integer, sequence, repeat

I need to produce a set of integers (from 1 to 20) of random length, and this needs be reproduced 30 times. To generate the random-length list, I use the `runif` function, which works. However, when I use the `rep` function to repeat this random list, it simply repeats the same list 30 times. What I want is the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
1 2 3 
etc.
```

Instead, the `runif` produces a list and `rep` repeats it 30 times, so it looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
etc.
```

I’d ideally like R to run the `runif` command 30 times. Now, I don’t know how to write a loop for this, and I also don’t know how to use something more elegant than loops. I tried using `repeat` function, but that one doesn’t produce integers, but lists which I cannot use for the computation I need.

How to do this?

Comment: As a note: `rep()` repeats the value of its argument a specified number of times, while `Replicate()` repeats the call from the argument, therefore, `rep()` produces identical sequences, while `Replicate()` would produce different sequences at each function call.

Answer (score 3):

Using:

```
# using set.seed for reproducibility
set.seed(171223)

# create a vector of end-points
ends <- sample(20, 30, TRUE)

# create a list of vector, each from 1 to an end point in 'ends'
lst <- Map(':', 1, ends)
```

gives this list (first 5 elements shown):

> ```
> > lst[1:5]
> [[1]]
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> [[3]]
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> [[4]]
> [1] 1 2 3 4
>
> [[5]]
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
> ```

If you want it in one vector, you can wrap it in `unlist`:

```
lst2 <- unlist(Map(':', 1, ends))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > lst2
>   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  1  2  3  4  5
>  [55]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3
> [109]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  1
> [163]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
> [217]  1  2  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15  1  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
> ```

Comment: instead of unlist, use `mapply`

Comment: @Onyambu `mapply` also returns a list, so you will still need `unlist`

Comment: right. it returns unlist due to the different lengths. thanks

Comment: @Onyambu the differing lengths aren't the reason `mapply` isn't returning a vector; for example `mapply(':', 1, rep(5,3))` returns a matrix and not a vector; to get a vector, you need to wrap it in `c()`

Answer (score 3):

You could replicate `1:sample(20, 1)` 30 times, as follows.

```
replicate(30, 1:sample(20, 1))
```

This produces a length 30 list, which would look like the following (only first 3 elements shown).

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

...
```

If a single vector result is desired, simply wrap the expression in `unlist()`.

```
unlist(replicate(30, 1:sample(20, 1)))
```

Comment: nice! wrap it in `unlist` to get expected output?

Comment: sorry, after in the source of the question text I think OP wants a list ... (see the edit)

Comment: Got it.  Thanks @Jaap